# Hide active term from the term page

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I have an article content type that has a taxonomy reference field that stores the author name. It can hold multiple authors in case the article is authored by more than one author.

As per the image given below, on the author term view page, I need to show only the co-authors names, hiding the current author.
ie, if I take the **Author1**'s page, the authors field should hide the **Author1**'s name from the display and show other authors names only.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this using views?

Comment: How is this "Author1, Author2" portion generated? Is this list an entity reference field being rendered as a field? Or is this an embedded view?

Comment: @Joseph It's an entity reference field rendered as a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using the views with the help of contextual filters.

1. Created a view block with taxonomy terms - unformatted list of fields.
2. Added only Name Field

[image]

3. In contextual filters, selected Term ID and configured the following way:
   a. When the filter value is NOT available - Provide default value: Taxonomy Term ID from URL and select "Load default filter from term page"

[image]

b. In the more section, select "Exclude" option. This is the option which does the magic. This will remove the filtered value from the view display

[image]